# "Воспрещён" или "запрещён"?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, семантика, общие-вопросы, приставка

Объясните, пожалуйста, что это за слово такое — "воспрещён"? Почему вместо понятного и доходчивого — "запрещён" — очень часто употребляют "воспрещён"? Особенно в надписях в транспорте. Спасибо, с уважением...

Answer (score 4):

Интересно сравнить значения приставок: приставка ЗА используется при образовании глаголов совершенного вида и обозначает завершенность действия (шифровать - зашифровать).

Приставка ВОЗ также может образовывать глаголы совершенного вида, но при этом следует учитывать ее центральное значение "направленность вверх", которое также можно рассматривать выражение интенсивности и полноты действия. Поэтому мы говорим наградить - вознаградить, благодарить - возблагодарить, гордиться - возгордиться.

Таким образом, в  глаголах  "воспретить - воспрещать" приставка ВОЗ имеет дополнительное значение абсолютного запрета.

Comment: Все надписи официальные, но, вероятно, степень официальности  тоже бывает разная. Входить куда не следует — воспрещено, а купаться и рвать цветы на клумбе — запрещено.

Answer (score 3):

Запрещен -- нейтральный вариант, воспрещен -- официальный.Воспрещён - слово, заимствованное  из церковнославянского : вос+ претить.